Function of exponential random variables
I have $20$ exponential random variables with mean $\alpha$ representing delays $D_n: n \in\{1,\ldots, 20\}$.
I have 20 random variables denoting power $P_n^{'}: n \in\{1,\ldots, 20\}$. which depends on the above delay distribution as determined by
$$
P_n^{\prime}=\exp \left(-\beta D_n \right) \cdot 10^{\frac{-\mathrm{Z}_n}{10}}
$$ where $Z_n \sim N\left(0, \zeta^2\right)$ is a Normal random variable.
Consider the normalized powers given as below:
$$
P_n=\frac{1}{K+1} \frac{P_n^{\prime}}{\sum_{n=1}^N P_n^{\prime}}+\delta(n-1)
\frac{K}{K+1}
$$
where $\delta($.$)$ is Dirac's delta function and $K$ is a constant.
Note that $P_1$  has an extra term $\frac{K}{K+1}$.
Can someone help me find the distribution (pdf) of  $P_n: n \in\{1,\ldots, 20\}$. I understand that $\{P_2,\ldots P_{20}\}$ have the same distribution and $P_1$ will have a different distribution due to the extra term.
My final goal is to see how much $P_1$ is bigger than $P_i$, when  $i \neq 1$. So can someone help me establish the distribution of $\frac{P_1}{P_i}$ where $i \neq 1$.
I am not sure how to approach this since there is many functions involved.
